# Determine the return-type of a function which is given as a templated-parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function with a templated parameter which accepts another function.  Within that function, I'd like to call a different template function which needs to be instantiated with the return-type of function argument.

Since I probably screwed that last paragraph up, let me attempt to clarify with an example:

```
template <typename funT>
void foo(funT function_to_call)
{
    auto data = bar<funT::return_value>();
    /// do some stuff with data.
    /// call function_to_call, but bar needed to be called first.
}
```

How do get funT::return_value ?

Many thanks,

Comment: The question has been market as a duplicate of an unrelated one, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes,  the answer has nothing to do with my question as far as I can tell, except they both have to do with C++ templates.

Comment: Anyway, you can access the return type by using  `std::result_of<funT()>::type`, provided `funT` doesn't take any argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use type traits in particular `std::result_of` in the following manner:

```
template <typename funT>
void foo(funT function_to_call) {
  auto data = bar<typename std::result_of<decltype(function_to_call)&()>::type>();
  //...
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/105d00a350dfbd7f)

You could also further generalize to accept any kind of function along with its input arguments by using variadic templates in the following manner:

```
template <typename funT, typename ...Args>
void foo(funT function_to_call, Args... args) {
  auto data = bar<typename std::result_of<funT(Args...)>::type>();
  ...
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/552a896152f532cd)

Comment: Is there any difference between that and just using `decltype(function_to_call())` ?

Comment: @Alejandro Yes there is, because `decltype(function_to_call())` results to the `function_to_call` return type (e.g., `int`) and calling `std::result_of<int>::type` will give you a compile error.

Comment: I was just talking about replacing `typename std::result_of<funT(Args...)>::type` with `decltype(function_to_call())`.  And in fact, it does work! check out [this live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4b297ff50d458cf).

Comment: @Alejandro Sorry, I though you were reffering to `typename std::result_of<decltype(function_to_call())>::type`, I don't know is there?

Comment: In general, they don't do the same thing, because `result_of` has some special rules regarding pointer-to-member-function types. However, that can only be meaningful if you have at least one argument. Also, depending on how you're using `result_of`, it can sometimes be a bit trickier or more confusing to correctly handle functors that have lvalue/rvalue-qualified overloads for `operator()`. In the specific case here though, I believe they are equivalent.

Comment: @hvd , thanks for the clarification! I knew they behaved similarly for cases like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using `result_of` as others have suggested,  you can also use `decltype`.

For the case where `function_to_call` accepts no parameters, you can do the following:

```
auto data = bar<decltype(function_to_call())>();
```

However, for a more generic case, as @101010 has pointed out, you can have your function accept any number of arguments. The resulting code would look like this:

```
template <typename funT, typename ...Args>
void foo(funT function_to_call, Args&&... args) 
{
   auto data = bar<decltype(function_to_call(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>();
}
```

For the cases that I've tried, `decltype` and `std::result_of` have the same functionality with regards to returning the correct type if the function type being passed in isn't a pointer-to-member, as @hvd pointed out. Looking  looking through the g++ source, `std::result_of` is often implemented in terms of `decltype` for the case described above.

Using this seems much cleaner and more readable to me than the `typename std::result_of<...>::type` alternative, although the C++14 `std::result_of_t` option is quite attractive as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typename std::result_of<funT()>::type` to fit your needs, or `std::result_of_t<funT()>` if you have access to C++14.